# AJAX DOM elements not saved on back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a list of data that a user can paginate to by using AJAX data to and appends that data to a container. If the user clicks on any entry to go to another page, and they click the native back-button on the browser, any AJAX append data is not listed on the DOM anymore. How can I solve this issue? Is this a jQuery issue?

I've tried changing the URL hash when the pagination occurs (#page2), but it still doesn't stay there once they hit back.

Any ideas?

Comment: You have to use history.pushState() and then handle the `popstate` event when they click the back button to update your page.

Comment: The Back button asks the browser to load a different page. Anything you've loaded in the current page will be lost unless you take some specific action to preserve it. You could look at localStorage or cookies, perhaps, but you'll still need some code to apply it to the page you're loading. See @MikeEdwards comment as well.

Comment: @MikeW not entirely true. Can run single page apps that utilize history to present different content but all within same page

Comment: @MikeEdwards so you have to not allow use pushState, but save the data somewhere, so it can add it back to the DOM? Just by using pushState it won't force the browser to cache the current page before going to the next one?

Comment: I've never actually used pushState directly so my outline is very high-level.  I'm just trying to point you in the right direction with some keywords to search for, that's why it's a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have to write the data somewhere for the data to still be there.  And without client side persistence, that means server side persistence.  Which means as they edit the data, you have to write it back to a server.  I know there are some technologies coming into browsers that allow some version of persistence on the client, but I haven't researched them myself.

You could look at http://tiddlywiki.com/.  That single page application uses various mechanisms including a trusted applet in certain browsers to rewrite data back into the page on the file system, so that the changes the user makes are persisted and available when the user comes back to it.  But that's different from living in http:// land.  In the web world, you rewrite persistent data back to the server.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow - look at a page like foursquare. You can scroll down on your activity feed, and it will append the data for you. Then go into a item, the hit the back-button. The content will still be there. I'm not looking to save the data, just have it added to the cache of the browser. It shouldn't load a new version of a page on back button. Right?